# Change visibility of the first item's child in ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have `ListView` control in my wpf window, which includes custom template and has `ItemSource` binded to a string collection:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfStrings}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">                       
                <Expander Visibility="{Binding ToSomethingIDontKnowTo}"/>                        
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>            
</ListView>
```

I need the `Expander` to be shown only for the first line. I know that first element style can be changed using `Trigger` like this:

```
<Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="0">
            <Setter Property="SomeProperty" Value="SomeValue" />
        </Trigger>               
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

but I have not found a way to apply this to the child control of `ListViewItem`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can trigger `Expander` Visibility

```
       <ListView AlternationCount="{Binding ItemsSource.Count, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"  ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfStrings}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Expander Header="My">
                        <Expander.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="Expander">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"></Setter>
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding (ItemsControl.AlternationIndex), RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListViewItem}}" Value="0">
                                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"></Setter>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </Expander.Style>
                    </Expander>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```